# KafkaIO watermark not advancing

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have the below pipeline for testing purposes:

```java
pipeline.apply(
  "ReadFromKafka",
  KafkaIO
    .read()
    .withBootstrapServers("kafkabroker")
    .withoutMetadata()
).apply(
  "OutputCount"
  Window
    .into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
    .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
    .discardingFiredPanes()
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
).apply(
  "AccumlateCount",
  Combine.globally(Count.combineFn()).withoutDefaults()
).apply(
  "PrintCount",
  MapElements.via(
    new SimpleFunction() {
      override def apply(count: Long): Void = {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("CountLogger").info(count.toString)
        null
      }
    }
  )
)
```

When I run this on dataflow I noticed that in the Dataflow pipline UI, the "Data watermark" metric in "Step Summary" is always "-". I'm producing events to Kafka every 30 seconds for about 5 minutes. It never got to printing the count to the logger for the 1 minute windows. Shouldn't the watermark be advancing since KafkaIO uses the processing time?

Comment: Yes, it should advance the watermark. Please provide the job_id if you have one, I am interested in taking a look. As a test, can you run it with direct runner?

Comment: Hey Raghu the job id is "2018-02-13_13_16_24-16149264018260697356". I tested using the direct runner and the trigger does seem to fire.

Comment: Looks like some of the partitions don't have any records. The way default watermark in KafkaIO is quite bad. Some of the partitions in your topic don't seem to have any records. That is ok. The deafult watermark should just return current time. I am about submit a PR to support Kafka server side timestamps properly as part of that I will fix the default watermark as well. Please see the answer below for work around.

Comment: The reason direct-worker functioned ok is that it has single split. i.e. all the Kafka partitions are read by a single consumer. So it didn't matter if some of the partitions were idle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way default watermark works in KafkaIO currently is quite bad. It does not handle idle partitions properly. It just returns processing time of the last record. Since some of the partitions in your topic don't seem to have any records, your watermark does not progress at all. The deafult watermark should just return current time. I am about submit a PR to support Kafka server side timestamps properly as part of that I will fix the default watermark as well. For now please try this work around:

```
[...]
  KafkaIO
    .read()
    .withBootstrapServers("kafkabroker")
    .withWatermarkFn(kv -> Instant.now()) // <<< what KafkaIO should do.
    .withoutMetadata()
[...]
```

**[Update]**
Unfortunately this is not a complete work around either. KafkaIO reader would still return MIN_TIMESTAMP until it reads the first record even with the above work around. If you want to test it out in Dataflow, try with a topic that has just single partition. It is a not an ideal fix, but this will be fixed in master this week (will be part of 2.4 release, scheduled for next month.).

**[Update:2]**: will be fixed as part of https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4680/

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you have a JIRA ticket I can follow? Thanks

Comment: Just pushed my changes to https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4680
Tracking jira : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-591.
Need to add documentation. Please take a look . at `ProcessingTimePolicy` (which will be the default policy).

Comment: I saw that in the PR that you added support for Kafka CreateTime timestamps. Would using this option result in a possibility of records being marked as late?

Comment: 'ProcessingTimePolicy' uses current time on Beam workers. So none of the records will be marked late. 'late' records arrive usually when you are using custom timestamp (based on a field in the message for example).